# How to Consolidate Many Classes and Avoid instanceof?

Tags: java

The program I'm helping to develop is supposed to output several dynamically generated questions for the user to answer. The questions are of different types and have a corresponding class `Constraint` that they fill with the user-given information. My question is how to create uniform behavior for the different constraints.

```
                    ---->Constraint<--------------------
                    |                  |               |
                  FConstraint        PConstraint    TConstraint
                  |         |
            UConstraint AConstraint
```

The base class `Constraint` is empty, as is TConstraint.

`UConstraint`, `PConstraint` and `AConstraint` share three variables. However, `UConstraint`and `AConstraint` have one additional variable that `PConstraint` doesn't have.

I feel like I'm trying to hammer through a brick wall with some pincers. My one thought is to provide an abstract method to Constraint with the signature:

```
// All answers are of type string.
abstract void setValue(string variable, string answer);
```

Which are implemented by every `Constraint` subclass. However, passing a string to determine which variable to set seems error-prone and a similarly bad code smell.

The second option was to move the three similar variables up into Constraint, but that still leaves `UConstraint, AConstraint` with that extra bit of information I might need to set. It doesn't help that `TConstraint` doesn't need any of those.

My current brute-force "Screw this design." solution is an `instanceof` soup in which I check and fill in the missing Constraint-specific information.

```
Object constraint = item.getConstraint();

if (constraint instanceof AConstraint) {
    AConstraint constraint = (AConstraint) constraint;

    if (constraint.getValue() == null) {
        constraint.setValue(string);
    } else if (constraint.getKey() == null) {
        constraint.setKey(string);
    } // More of the same.
} else if (constraint instanceof PConstraint) {
    // As the above if() group.
} // etc.
```

Is there a better solution to this design than the abstract function?

Comment: what beef do you have with interfaces? ;)

Comment: @user1329572: No beef, I didn't write them. I'm just trying to improve upon their design now :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question don't have enough information about actual work you need to do in each case, but generally such code:

```
Object constraint = item.getConstraint();

if (constraint instanceof AConstraint) {
    // Work
} else if (constraint instanceof PConstraint) {
    // Work
} // etc.
```

is a strong smell to use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) and refactor into a something like this:

```
Constraint constraint = item.getConstraint();
constraint.doWork(...);
```

where specific classes would look something like this:

```
public class AConstraint {
  public ... doWork(...) {
    if (getValue() == null) {
      setValue(string);
    } else if (getKey() == null) {
      setKey(string);
    } // More of the same.      
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! I noticed too late that I didn't specify what exactly I had to do. Constraints only carry specific information in the form of the variables I mentioned. The answer fills in one of these potentially empty member variables of the Constraint. Each instanceof casts the Object to the specific Constraint and goes through each field, identifying the empty one. Does this help? I added an edit which clarifies this as well.

Comment: Doesn't really make much difference, but I've updated my example with your own code.

Comment: Oooh, I just understood the concept. Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Use this principle

Program in interfaces, and encapsulate the behaviors that keeps changing in abstract class or Interfaces.

eg: For your above given example

Interface - Constraint

Abstract Class - FConstraint

Concrete Class     - PConstraint, TConstraint, UConstraint, AConstraint

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public interface Constraint{}

public abstract class VariableConstraint implements Constraint 
{ 
  /* hold 3 shared variables here */
}

public class UConstraint extends VariableConstraint{}
public class PConstraint extends VariableConstraint{}
public class AConstraint extends VariableConstraint{}

public abstract class EmptyConstraint implements Constraint {}

public class TConstraint extends EmptyConstraint {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify common functionality in `Constraint`: any operation that you want to be able to perform on a `Constraint` object (which could in fact be an object of one of the sub types), you have a method for that functionality in `Constraint` that you override in subclasses.

You can have trivial (e.g. empty) implementation for the parent classes where that functionality does not make sense.

This way you do not need to concern yourself with the concrete class of the object, just use the facility provided by the superclass

Answer (score 1):

Have the `Constraint` as an Interface. Define an abstract class which extends this `Constraint` and this should have the shared variables. `UConstraint`, `AConstraint` should extend this abstract class which has the shared variables. The rest of the classes can directly implement the `Constraint` interface. The instance of code should be changed like

```
Constraint constraint = item.getConstraint();
constraint.doWork(..);
```

Always the better design is to write code against an interface